# Testing Django - Saving test DB

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

In my tests.py I have:

```
from functions import function
from .models import Student

def setUp(self):
    self.student = Student.objects.create(status=False)

def test_function():
    function() # function changes student's status to True
    print(self.student.status) # I'm still getting False
```

While running tests, my function doesn't change the attributes of objects created for tests so i can't test if function works properly.
Is there a way to make sth like scenario below:

- Object for testing is created.
- I'm calling function which changes object's attribute.
- I can check if attributte was changed.

Function I want to test doesn't return anything, it only changes attriubtes of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Let's put `setUp` in class which is your TestCase class. To do this lets create class for example `TestXXX` and inside put `setup` and your `test_function`:**

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestXXX(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.student = Student.objects.create(status=False)

    def test_function():
        function() # function changes student's status to True
        print(self.student.status) # I'm still getting False
```

**Function which you run make some changes in your DB but new data is not reflect on your `self.students` variable so u need get new data using:**

```
self.student.status.refresh_from_db()
print(self.student.status)
```

[Model.refresh_from_db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db)